# MS Word suddently becoming dead slow

Tags: microsoft-word, performance

I am maintaining a rather large MS Word document (600 pages, including pictures but very few styles; the file size is 8 MB). Until now I could edit it with normal response times.

But today, all of a sudden, some operations are terribly slow (like search/replace taking 10 minutes when they took 3 seconds before, but not only).

I made no significant changes to the document, nor to my way to rework it, nor to my machine (besides the remote updates by Microsoft).

What could be the cause?

Comment: You can test if the cause is in *MS Word* itself, as opposed to a change in the document or PC, by opening it on another PC, or on the same PC using a different application, such as free *LibreOffice*. You don't even need to install *LibreOffice*; just make a Live Ubuntu USB and boot from it -- *LibreOffice* is already installed. BTW, 1. What version of Office? 2. How are auto backup files maintained (running out of space)?

Comment: @DrMoishePippik: this is Office Professional Plus 2019, Version 2307 32 bits; plenty of disk space.

Comment: @DrMoishePippik: good suggestion. I tried on an older version of the document (just 10 pages shorter), and the same operations were running at normal speed. I might try to discard the new content to see (if I can).

Comment: Perhaps something new was added, such as creating a link to an online image or a network resource, adding a table of contents or index, or creating a VBA macro, that is slowing it?

Comment: That's actually a small file size if you have many pictures. Assuming you have *linked* pictures, is it possible you have one or two that got embedded and are, perhaps, rather large byte size?

Comment: @DrMoishePippik: there have been no change of this nature. I must add that the document contains numerous internal hyperlinks ("Place in this document"). Maybe I have reached a threshold.

Comment: @Yorik: unless unknowingly, there are no linked items in this document.